# error installing openni_kinnect

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubunto 10.10 and trying to install the kinect drivers.
I got as far as
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers
cd drivers
make
make install

but make install runs for a while then fails. Here are the last few linessudo cp -f ./openni/lib/*.so /usr/lib/
sudo cp -f ./openni/lib/*.xml /etc/primesense/
sudo cp -r ./openni/include/ni/* /usr/include/openni/
sudo cp -f ./openni/bin/ni* /usr/bin/
sudo /bin/bash ./CONTROL/openni_postinst
postinst called with unknown argument `'
make: *** [install_openni] Error 1

how do I fix it?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10466/error-installing-openni_kinnect/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You only need to install either via packages or from source.
So if `sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect` ran without errors, its already done.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1